# django - how to return the same page with all data when form.is_valid() is false

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am newbie to django and I am struggling for a longer time with form which doesn't display all data after submitting with error.
On my application to book fitness classes there is sth like header which display data of chosen training,there are also fields to input data of training participant and there is a submit button. After submitting when form.is_valid() is false I would like to display the same page with: data of chosen training, data inputed to fields and validation information for all fields which were filled wrongly. Displaying data inputed to fields and validation information works, but displaying data of chosen training doesn't work. I attach printscreen to show this situation.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**views.py**

```
class BookView(View):
    """
    Booking page - getting data of trainings and
    posting data of booking to db
    """
    template_name = 'club/book.html'
    form_class = BookingForm

    def post(self, request, training_id):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Well done! Fitness Class has been booked for you. If you would like to cancel booked fitness class, please contact our office.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/book/' + training_id)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Oh snap! Fill/correct all fields and try submitting again.')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def get(self, request, training_id):
        training = get_object_or_404(Training,pk = training_id)
        form = self.form_class(instance=training)
        context = {'training': training,
                   'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**book.html**

```
{% extends 'club/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load bootstrap %}
<div>
    <h4>Please input your details to book the following Fitness Class</h4>
    <br></br>
    <div class="training-context">
        <label>{{training.name}} {{training.training_date}} {{training.start_time}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
<br></br>
<form action=" " method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-group">
{{form.first_name|bootstrap}}
<p></p>
{{form.last_name|bootstrap}}
<p></p>
{{form.email|bootstrap}}
<p></p>
{{form.phone|bootstrap}}
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="training" value={{training.id}}> 
<br></br>
<a href=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></a>
</form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Training(models.Model):
    """Class for plan training"""
    STATE = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('I', 'Inactive'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey('TrnDesc')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor')
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(default='00:00:00')
    availability = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE, default='A')
    training_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name

class Booking(models.Model):
    """Data of people which book fitness classes"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    training = models.ForeignKey('Training')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.training.name.name
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    url(r'^book/(?P<training_id>\d+)/$', BookView.as_view(), name='book'),
    ]
```

Comment: Use [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get` you're rendering with `context = { 'training': training, 'form': form }` while in your `post`, you return only `{ 'form' : form }` in case of an error (when form is invalid).

You should return `training` object either way, as it's always displayed:

```
if not form.is_valid():
    return render(request, self.template_name, { 'training': training, 'form': form })
```

Apart from that, consider using Django's generic editing views such as `FormView` or `CreateView` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added 'training':training to return in post and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the correct classes for the functionality you are implementing. You are creating an entity in the database, so you should subclass CreateView. Once you've done that, you can remove most of your logic, and just define `get_context_data` to return the relevant Training object.

Comment: I am trying to use CreateView, but I have a problem with getting a context of training which should be displayed. My get_context_data looks following: def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['training'] = Training
        return context           but it doesn't work. Could you give me some guidance with that?

Comment: You still need to actual query the training item you want. `context['training'] = Training.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['training_id'])`.

Comment: Its already in your context. You are running a query for it twice. Its in there as object. You can write your whole view with 3 lines.